# MySQL query nested where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In my database, there are four types of individuals, `youngOrc`, `oldOrc`, `youngHuman`, `oldHuman`.

An individual belongs to a type conditional on a date range. Thus, I have tables like this for each type:

```
youngOrcList
-------------------
individual_id, 
start_date, 
end_date
```

This means that the guy with `individual_id` is a `youngOrc` between the start and end date. He may be something else outside that range. Similarly, I have a `youngHuman` table.

Now, the real table of interest that I want to filter is events:

```
events
------------------
source_individual_id
target_individual_id
event_date
```

Events table records all events between two individuals in my realm. I want to filter so that I only select `events` between `youngOrc` and `youngHuman`.

So this is a "nested" condition of sort, where I need both `events.source_individual_id IN youngOrcList` AND `events.event_date BETWEEN youngOrcList.start_date AND youngOrcList.end_date`. How to make this work?

(Also, any suggestion regarding a better title would be great. I don't even know what to call this and thus unable to Google effectively.)

Comment: What did you try so far? Also it will help if you provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: It sounds like you have a bad schema.  To me, there is no reason to have 4 separatetables for these for classes of individuals.  Why not just a single table with all individuals.  Old/young is really just a property of the individual (and I'm guessing could change over time - so what are you going to move individuals from one table to another as they age in your current scheme?).  Also human vs. orc could be looked at as a property of the individual as well.  Why not just have individuals and events which relates to individuals?

Comment: The youngOrcList things are tables I create myself to facilitate the query. The real schema has a table that maps individuals to their types conditional on date range like you said. Would using that table be easier for me?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all events between youngOrc and youngHuman:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 Events e
 WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT * FROM youngHumanList 
       WHERE individual_id IN (e.source_individual_id, e.target_individual_id)
             AND e.event_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
   AND EXISTS (
       SELECT * FROM youngOrcList
       WHERE individual_id IN (e.source_individual_id, e.target_individual_id)
             AND e.event_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
```

Comment: Could you explain how this work? First, I thought `IN` must be followed by a `SELECT` subquery. I didn't expect `IN (e.source_individual_id, e.target_individual_id)` to work (it does). Second, `e.event_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date` -- how do I know it's the `event_date` associated with the `individual_id` in question?

Comment: `IN` operator accept a list of values as well as sub-queries. So you can write `WHERE a IN (1, 2, 3)`.  As for `event_date` it always comes from current record in Events record set. So both exists clauses will have same e.event_date value, but we are looking for existence of Orc and Human separately and only if both exist for an event we return the record

Comment: So, even though `events` has millions of rows, in each iteration, `e.source_individual_id`, `e.target_individual_id`, and `e.event_date` are all looking at the same row?

Comment: Yes, and that is controlled by alias `e` which is pointing to the same record

Answer (score 0):

You can use join on tables. They can be joined on a field `individual_id` so then the only condition left for `WHERE` clause will be the date condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM youngOrcList AS o
JOIN events AS e ON e.source_individual_id = o.individual_id
JOIN youngHumanList AS h ON h.individual_id = e.target_individual_id
WHERE e.event_date BETWEEN o.start_date AND o.end_date
AND e.event_date BETWEEN h.start_date AND h.end_date
```

Alternatively, the `WHERE` condition could be:

```
WHERE e.event_date > MAX(o.start_date, h.start_date)
AND e.event_date < MIN(o.end_date, h.end_date)
```